# Alert message not showing when answer is correct from input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

// Create an array with each indicative in French and English - Present, Imperfect, and Future

```
const frenchPresImpFut = ['Je suis', 'Tu es', 'Il/Elle est', 'Nous sommes', 'Vous êtes', 'Ils/Elles sont', "J'étais", 'Tu étais', 'Il/Elle était', 'Nous étions', 'Vous étiez', 'Ils/Elles étaient', 'Je serai', 'Tu seras', 'Il/Elle sera', 'Nous serons', 'Vous serez', 'Ils/Elles seront'];

const englishPresImpFut = ['I am', 'You are', 'He/She is', 'We are', 'You are', 'They are', 'I was', 'You were', 'He/She was', 'We were', 'You are', 'They were', 'I will', 'You will', 'He/She will', 'We will', 'You will', 'They will'];
```

// Create a function to generate a random word from the French array and then validate if user answer is correct

```
function randomWord() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * frenchPresImpFut.length);
    let frenchWord = frenchPresImpFut[randomNumber];
    let englishWord = englishPresImpFut[randomNumber];
    let $guess = $('#userGuess').val();

    $('.randomFrenchWord').text(frenchWord);

    $('#nextWord').click(function () {
        if ($guess === englishWord) {
            console.log('Correct');
        }
    })
}
```

// Call function to insert random word to page

```
randomWord();
```

Comment: You're logging `Correct` to the console. Did you check the console? If you need an alert, try using `alert("Correct")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some refactoring to the code because you would run into problems with your current code even if it works. The `randomWord()` function should be different from the function that checks the value entered by the user and you will call this function in two scenarios i.e 1. when the page loads and 2. when you click the Next button. And then `checkAnswer()` to validate the user's input.

Note the changes made to the HTML.

I am sure you get the idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  randomWord();

  $('#nextWord').on('click', () => {
    randomWord();
  });

  $('#checkAnswer').on('click', () => {
    checkAnswer();
  });
});

let word = "";

const randomWord = () => {
  const frenchPresImpFut = ['Je suis', 'Tu es', 'Il/Elle est', 'Nous sommes', 'Vous êtes', 'Ils/Elles sont', "J'étais", 'Tu étais', 'Il/Elle était', 'Nous étions', 'Vous étiez', 'Ils/Elles étaient', 'Je serai', 'Tu seras', 'Il/Elle sera', 'Nous serons', 'Vous serez', 'Ils/Elles seront'];
  const englishPresImpFut = ['I am', 'You are', 'He/She is', 'We are', 'You are', 'They are', 'I was', 'You were', 'He/She was', 'We were', 'You are', 'They were', 'I will', 'You will', 'He/She will', 'We will', 'You will', 'They will'];

  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * frenchPresImpFut.length);
  let frenchWord = frenchPresImpFut[randomNumber];
  let englishWord = englishPresImpFut[randomNumber];
  $('.randomFrenchWord').text(frenchWord);
  word = englishWord;
}

const checkAnswer = () => {
  let guess = $('#userGuess').val();
  guess === word ? alert('Correct') : alert('incorrect');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="randomFrenchWord"></p>
<input id="userGuess">
<button id="checkAnswer">Answer</button>
<button id="nextWord">Next Word</button>
<p class="englishTranslation"></p>
```

Comment: Right thanks, didn't see that. BUT even with the alert change, it's still not showing an alert or previous even logging to console when provided the correct answer..

Comment: So it would also mean that the console.log doesn't run too? How do you call the `randomWord()` ? can you paste your HTML form?

Comment: <p class="randomFrenchWord"></p>
<input id="userGuess">
<button id="nextWord">Next</button>
<p class="englishTranslation"></p>

Comment: You need to call the function at a time when the user has finished entering the value in the input. either with `onsubmit="randomWord()"` or onblur.

Comment: Also, be sure to you have added jquery on your file.

Comment: It's still not working, I added an else clause to the function to else alert('Incorrect') and the alert is showing up when I click on the button for "Incorrect". So I think there is an issue with the actual function for checking to see if the $guess === englishWord ?

Comment: I have posted a working solution, you can try it out. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892678/1452861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892678/1452861)

Comment: Great! you can accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nextWord').click(function () {
            randomWord();
        });
    });

    function randomWord() {
        const frenchPresImpFut = ['Je suis', 'Tu es', 'Il/Elle est', 'Nous sommes', 'Vous êtes', 'Ils/Elles sont', "J'étais", 'Tu étais', 'Il/Elle était', 'Nous étions', 'Vous étiez', 'Ils/Elles étaient', 'Je serai', 'Tu seras', 'Il/Elle sera', 'Nous serons', 'Vous serez', 'Ils/Elles seront'];
        const englishPresImpFut = ['I am', 'You are', 'He/She is', 'We are', 'You are', 'They are', 'I was', 'You were', 'He/She was', 'We were', 'You are', 'They were', 'I will', 'You will', 'He/She will', 'We will', 'You will', 'They will'];
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * frenchPresImpFut.length);
        let frenchWord = frenchPresImpFut[randomNumber];
        let englishWord = englishPresImpFut[randomNumber];
        let $guess = $('#userGuess').val();

        $('.randomFrenchWord').text(frenchWord);

        if ($guess === englishWord) {
            console.log('Correct');
        }
    }
```